# Write some random numbers to the pipe?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pipe

my question is can I write an integer to pipe ? and how ?

I need to make 3 processes first one generate 2 numbers, second make sum of the numbers, third print the result (USING PIPE)

Thanks all

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail on what you're doing if you want more of an answer than "yes, with `write(2)`".

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: yes it is

Comment: Homework questions should be tagged |homework|.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complicated part of what you're trying to do is creating the pipeline.  You could just have the shell do it for you...

```
$ ./makenumbers | ./addnumbers | ./printresult
```

but that's boring, eh?  And you have to have three executables.  So let's have a look at what those vertical bars are doing at the C level.

You create a pipe with the [`pipe`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/pipe/) system call.  You reassign standard input/output with [`dup2`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/dup/).  You create new processes with [`fork`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/fork/), and you wait for them to terminate with [`waitpid`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/wait/).  A program to set the whole thing up would look something like this:

```
int
main(void)
{
    pid_t children[2];
    int pipe1[2], pipe2[2];
    int status;

    pipe(pipe1);
    pipe(pipe2);

    children[0] = fork();
    if (children[0] == 0)
    {
        /* in child 0 */
        dup2(pipe1[1], 1);
        generate_two_numbers_and_write_them_to_fd_1();
        _exit(0);
    }

    children[1] = fork();
    if (children[1] == 0)
    {
        /* in child 1 */
        dup2(pipe1[0], 0);
        dup2(pipe2[1], 1);
        read_two_numbers_from_fd_0_add_them_and_write_result_to_fd_1();
        _exit(0);
    }

    /* parent process still */
    dup2(pipe2[0], 0);
    read_a_number_from_fd_0_and_print_it();

    waitpid(children[0], &status, 0);
    waitpid(children[1], &status, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note:

- I left out all error handling, because that would make the program about three times longer.  Your instructor wants you to include error handling.
- Similarly, I left out checking the exit status of the children; your instructor also wants you to check that.
- You do not *need* the `dup2` calls; you could just pass the pipe fd numbers to the subroutine calls.  But if you were [`exec`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/execve/)-ing a new binary in the child, which is more typical, you would need them.  You would then also have to worry about making sure all file descriptors numbered 3 and higher were closed.
- There is a reason I am using [`_exit`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/_exit/) instead of [`exit`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/exit/).  Try to figure out what it is.
- You need to use [`read`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/read/) and [`write`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/write/) instead of stdio.h calls in the subroutines called from child processes.  The reason is related to the reason I am using `_exit`.

Comment: waitpid needs 3 parameters (pid_t pid, int *status, int options), in this case the third parameter must be 0 (block current process until the child process is terminated).

Answer (score 3):

Since a pipe is just a file, you can use the [fprintf()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) function to convert a random number to text and write that to the pipe. For instance:

```
FILE *pipe = popen("path/to/your/program", "w");
if (pipe != NULL) {
    fprintf(pipe, "%d\n", rand());
    pclose(pipe);
}
```